# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create manifest file

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a Flask app on Google Cloud Engine and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create manifest file.
```

I created a new project but the problem persist. I am able to deploy example Flask app. I don't understand what problem this specific app has. Here are the details:

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
env_variables:
    CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD : ""
    CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME : ""
    CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME : "postgres"
    CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE_NAME : "postgres"
```

And this is what I have in my folder

```
.
..
.DS_Store
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
.mypy_cache
.swp
README.md
app.yaml
client
flaskr
gcskey.json
instance
main.py
requirements.txt
tests
venv
```

and is is my .gcloudignore

```
venv
gcpkey.json
gcskey.json
```

Comment: I think one of the files in your directory is causing the error. 1) Add `skip_files:` section to app.yaml to ignore everything not required to deploy. 2) Edit your question and include all error messages if you still have a problem.

Comment: Try increasing the deployment verbosity with [`--verbosity`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity), it may reveal details about the failure.